# Find all pairs of polynomials in (R[X])2 such that P(X2) = Q(X3)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find all pairs of polynomials  ( P(X), Q(X) )  in  ( R[X] )2  such that the polynomials  P(X2)  and  Q(X3)  are equal.

Can someone help me to resolve this ? I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\deg P(X^2)=2\deg P\le 4$, $\deg Q(X^3)=3\deg Q$. So this degree must be a multiple of $2$ and of $3$ and $\le 4$. This leave us with degree $\le 0$ only, i.e., $P$ and $Q$ are constant (possibly $0$).